# Why does a gold badge have a post minimum?

Tags: discussion, badges

I noticed that [pigworker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/828361/pigworker?tab=summary) has a score of 2k in the [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) tag, having accumulated numerous great answers therein, but does not yet have a gold badge for Haskell. I imagine this is because, as one of the best-known researchers in the field, he focuses on quality and cares little for quantity. Why impose a minimum number of posts that excludes the likes of pigworker?

Comment: To prevent people like me from having too many shiny things.

Comment: Because it's perfectly possible to get 1k+ upvotes on a *single* question/answer - that doesn't mean you're necessarily an expert in that tag. So having at least 400 posts means not only do you have a broad enough overview of it, but with a 1000 upvotes, the community also thinks you know what you're talking about.

Comment: Especially since a gold tag-badge grants dupehammer powers, we don't want one tremendously popular answer to give a user this. They need to have broad experience in the tag as well.

Comment: @JonClements, wouldn't it work even better to, say, require a certain total score, plus some smaller score with each answer capped at 10 points or whatever?

Comment: I disagree with this question receiving so many downvotes; clearly, by the long comments both to the question and the answer, he touches upon a problem that at the least is worthy of some thought and consideration. Also, as indicated by the many upvotes, the comment from @JonClements really should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It might be more interesting if tag badges were adjusted to require a certain number of [nice answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer), at least for silver and above.

Specifically, instead of 200 answers period, gold could require 10 nice answers; silver could require 4 nice answers; and bronze 10 positively-scored answers instead (since requiring a single nice answer does nothing to prevent golden shots). (The total score requirement would remain the same for each.)

Out of the last 20 haskell gold badgers, 20 would qualify for the badge under my proposed rules. 16 have twice that, and a pretty sizeable number can go up to 30 or even 40 without trouble.
Of the last 10 c# badgers, 9 of them would qualify — the remaining candidate has only 8 nice answers. None of them would qualify with 20 or more required.

This would still prevent "golden shot" badge-holders, but wouldn't require so very many posts from very high quality posters. Requiring broad experience and dedication is all very well, but when you have 100+ answers with mean scores of 20+, that's more than plenty for a gold. And when the fastest way to get half a dozen badges would often be to simply throw out whatever random barely-acceptable answers come to your mind until you get the needed count, something is askew.

Comment: 50 or even 40 nice answers (in the specific tag) is too high a bar. It would be reasonable if it's implemented as an alternative to earning 1000 score on 400 answers.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Hmm, I think you're right. I've added some data and recalibrated my expectations. (This mostly just goes to show how good a candidate pigworker really is.)

Comment: The “10 nice answers” proposal still has the same problem. An SO user may write popular answers in the well-followed tag X, and questions in X might 5% of the times get tagged Y without being representative of Y. That would get the user the few nice answers they need for a Y gold badge, without being expert at Y.

Comment: For instance, I don't know anything about C++. With the current system, I have an undeserved silver badge from questions (usually wrongly) tagged both C and C++. With your proposal, I think I would be dangerously close to getting a C++ gold badge.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I don't know what you mean about "still has the same problem". Right now you're lacking 246 score and 50 posts to have a [c++] gold. This way, sure, you'd have enough posts (16), but it doesn't do anything about your score, and fixing those erroneous taggings would help either way. (A question that no longer has the wrong tag will no longer contribute to your tag score; the first revision's tagging is only relevant to *using* the dupehammer, not gaining it.)

Comment: I had not realized you were keeping the score requirement. My C++ example doesn't make sense in this case, but another objection is that some tags have few enough fans that 5 upvotes is about the maximum a perfect answer can hope to gain unless the tag is associated to more popular ones. In these tags you get to 1000 upvotes at about the same time as you get to 200 answers, but it might take a long time to reach any quota of nice answers. Since you seem to have the queries at your fingertips, how about running them over the floating-point tag?

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Looks fine. Both current badge-holders would easily qualify for the badge with my proposal. You have 28 posts, and Stephen Canon 48. Jon Skeet, with 33 and a 2k+ score, would get yet another new badge, but Mysticial, with 8 and a 1.7k score, would not, and no one else would qualify yet. Of the next three, Eric Postpischil is only a few dozen score away (by either the current or my proposed systems), while both of the others are blatant golden shot answers with only one nice answer.

Comment: I dislike this suggestion. If a user has a large quantity of upvoted answers, but very few of those answers get past 10 votes, he wouldn't get a well deserved gold badge. I only have [17 "nice answer" badges in JS](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/369727/nice-answers-by-user?UserId=1835379), with a score of `1929`... At the `1000` point, I didn't have 10 of those badges.

Comment: @Cerbrus: You can't make an omelet without breaking a few eggs, and the badges are always a little imprecise. My goal is to make them fit *better*, not *perfectly*. Still, something to consider. Sounds like it would have taken another couple hundred score after 1000 before you hit the 10-answer mark, which is less than most of the discrepancies here, but still a bit much.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: It may only be 100 rep points, but that's still 10 required upvotes on good answers that probably barely have any traffic left. If an answer doesn't get past +10 within it's first 24 hours, it gets rather difficult to get a nice answer badge on it.